# Python 3: using %s and .format()

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have finally switched from `%` to the `.format()` string formatting operator in my 2.x code in order to make it easier to migrate to 3.x in future. It was a bit surprising to find out that not only the `%`-style formatting remains in Py3, but it is widely used in the standard library code. It seems logical, because writing `'(%s)' % variable` is a bit shorter and maybe easier to comprehend than `'({})'.format(variable)`. But I'm still in doubt. Is it proper (pythonic?) to use both approaches in the code? 
Thank you.

Comment: `%` formatting is slightly faster. But if you're doing that much string formatting that it matters, you probably have other more important concerns.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Python 3.2 documentation said that, `%` will eventually go away.

http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting

> Since `str.format()` is quite new, a lot of Python code still uses the `%`
>   operator. However, because this old style of formatting will
>   eventually be removed from the language, `str.format()` should generally
>   be used.

But as [@regilero says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753844/python-3-using-s-and-format#comment30714285_14753974), **the sentence is gone from 3.3**, which might suggest it's not actually the case. There are some conversations [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Status-regarding-Old-vs-Advanced-String-Formating-tp4503327p4504193.html) that suggest the same thing.

As of [Python 3.4 the paragraph 7.1.1](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) reads:

> The % operator can also be used for string formatting. It interprets
>   the left argument much like a sprintf()-style format string to be
>   applied to the right argument, and returns the string resulting from
>   this formatting operation.

See also [Python 3.4 4.7.2 printf-style String Formatting.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, Vlad. Indeed, they say that in the documentation, but even the standard library of 3.x is flooded with `%`-like formatting :( It seems that there are not that many signs of getting rid from `%` at all. Anyway, sticking to `.format()` seems right :)

Comment: This sentence has been removed in python 3.3 documentation, it was still there in 3.2 http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting

Comment: just out of curiosity, is the older one going to be deprecated?

Comment: I just tested `bar = "baz"; print("foo %s" % bar)`, and it still worked in Python 3.4.3 (along with 2.7.3 and 2.6.6)

Answer (score -1):

"%s" is now "{}", so insted of adding %s replace it with {} where you would want to add the variable into the string.

```
def main():
    n="Python 3.+" 
    l="looks nice"
    f="does not look practical."


    print("This seems to be the new way {}".format(n)\
      + "will be working, rather than the ' % ',{} but {}".format(l,f))



main()

#In comparison to just injecting the variable
```

Output disregard the quotes they are for illustration reasons

"This seems to be the new way "Python 3.+"
will be working, rather than the '%;, "looks nice" but "does not look practical.""