# Having issues printing out totals with only two decimal points [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

My calculations seem to be showing as incorrect now despite the decimal format being correct.

```html
import time # It was reccommend in our text to always have your import data located outside of any loops, thus I put mine here.

while True: # This is the main, and only; while loop.  It will repeat the program and allow users to book more reservations depending on input.
    user_people = int(raw_input("Welcome to Ramirez Airlines!  How many people will be flying?"))
    user_seating = str(raw_input("Perfect!  Now what type of seating would your party prefer? We offer Economy, Business and First Class!"))
    
    else:
        before_discount = luggage_total + seats_total
        discount_amount = before_discount * discount_rate
        after_discount = before_discount - discount_amount

        print ('Unfortunately we were not able to discount this particular transaction, however you can learn how to save 10% on future flights through our Frequent Flyers program! Contact us for more info!')
        print ('The total tax amount for your order is: $%.2f') % (before_discount * tax_rate)
        print ('Your total amount due including taxes for your airfare is: $%.2f') % (before_discount * tax_rate + before_discount)

    
    user_continue = raw_input("Your reservation was submitted successfully.  Would you like to do another?")    
    if user_continue != 'yes':
        break

print('Thank you for flying with Ramirez Airlines!')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print 'Your total amount due is ${:.2f}'.format(totalCost)
```

And:

```
print 'Your total amount due is $%.2f' % totalCost
```

both print to two decimal places.

```
In [3]: 'Your total amount due is $%.2f' % 1.2234
Out[3]: 'Your total amount due is $1.22'



In [4]: 'Your total amount due is ${:.2f}'.format(1.2234)
Out[4]: 'Your total amount due is $1.22'
```

If you are adding two numbers you need parens for old style formatting:

```
In [6]: 'Your total amount due is $%.2f' % (1.2234 + 1.2324)
Out[6]: 'Your total amount due is $2.46'
In [7]: 'Your total amount due is ${:.2f}'.format(1.2234+   1.2324)
Out[8]: 'Your total amount due is $2.46'
```

Using an example from your code:

```
print ('Your total amount due including taxes for your airfare is: ${:.2f}'.format(tax_amount + after_tax )
```

Comment: Padraic, thanks for your help!  I managed to get most of my outputs to display as two decimals, but what about if I have to add two 'variables'?  For example, print ('Your subtotal for your seats and luggage is: $'), luggage_total +  seats_total)

Comment: No worries, just do `(var1 + var2)` as on the last example. I prefer using `str.format` as I think it is less prone to errors.

Comment: Same for a code like this: before_discount * tax_rate + before_discount

Comment: Yes just wrap it all in parens `(before_discount * tax_rate + before_discount)`

Comment: Hmm.  So, I managed to get everything to show as decimals but for some reason my calculations are now showing as incorrect when calculating tax, discount, etc.  I have edited my main code to show my program.. do you mind taking a quick look at it to see if you see any glaringly obvious issue?

Comment: No worries. I will take a quick look

Comment: I just now saved my edit -- you might want to refresh! Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72375/discussion-between-cory-ramirez-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 2):

```
total_cost = 1234.56789
print('Your total amount due is ${0:.2f}'.format(total_cost))

Your total amount due is $1234.57
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ('text'),("%.2f" % variable)
```

should do it

Comment: .format() is generally considered more 'pythonic' than %s style prints:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753844/python-3-using-s-and-format